# how to convert dynamic time to a static number in excel?

Tags: time

How can I convert a dynamic time to a static number in excel?
I would like to see in a cell, when it was filled with a data. 
Example: A1 filled with a character and I would like to see in A2 when A1 was filled.

Thx

Comment: Create proper handler in `Worksheet_Change()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the cell and paste it right back as 'Value':
CTRL+C, and then under Paste: Paste Values.

I am using this very often for many things; if you need it a lot, add the corresponding button to the top bar of Excel, then it's simply CTRL+C, click.